# Jsrender template call a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsrender

I have the following template:

```
<script id="testTemplate" type="text/x-template">
   <div class="btn-action">
      <button onclick='displayDiv(this.id, "${Status}")' id="temp-${tempId}">
        <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
      </button>
    </div>
</script>
```

The javascript is as below:

```
function displayDiv(clickedId, status) {
/*some code here*/
}
```

The type of ${Status} is a string.  The page however is rendered as below:

```
<button onclick="displayDiv(this.id, " pending')'="" id="temp-128"><i class="material-icons">more_vert</i></button>
```

And I get an error when I click on the button:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Any one can help with the correct syntaxe here please?  I am new to js-render and javascript coding.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`${Status}` is not valid syntax for JsRender. (It is correct syntax for [jQuery-templates](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl#example)).

You probably want something like:

```
  <button onclick='displayDiv(this.id, "{{:Status}}")' id="temp-{{:tempId}}">
```

See the [JsRender/JsViews documentation](https://www.jsviews.com/#assigntag)